# Can this $R^3$ vector space property be proven this way?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $a, b, c \in \Re³$, I want to prove that $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$ (as a step of proving that $\Re³$ is a vector space).

Is this sufficient to say that, given the definition of addition on $\Re³$,  and given that for any $u, v, w \in \Re$, we have $(u+v)+w = (u+v)+w$ then we can conclude that $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$ ?
Or is a complementary definition absolutely necessary in order for the definition to be complete?

Thank you

Comment: I would say this is not sufficient, assuming this is for a course.  The argument you give would not convince a grader that you actually understand the details hidden in "by definition" (i.e. what specific properties are being used here), and it sounds superficially like circular logic.  Vague phrases like "we can conclude" are used to **suppress** detail that you wish to leave to the reader to fill in: this is appropriate when writing for a research journal, but not for homework.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of a vector space $V$? If it says that $(V,+)$ should be an abelian group, then we have by definition that $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$, i.e., the associativity. And in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we know that addition of vectors is associative, because it is associative in each coordinate, because $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.